# How to open .shp file for editing some latitiude and longtitude co-ordinates?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I have a shapefile. I want to just check data co-ordinates latitude and longitude values in .shp file.
I have using QGIS -2.8.6 , and .shp file automatically loaded in QGIS and it will show polygon output for given co-ordinates.

But, I want to see what is in .shp file. I want the polygon co-ordinates which is shown as a polygon in QGIS. Can you tell me how to see my polygon co-ordinates if the format is in .shp? How can I extract those co-ordinates in CSV or any format?

Comment: Huh? There is no coordinate data in the .shx file.

Comment: @Vince, I means Using qgis I have seen all polygons boundaries,there was 5-6 polygons co-ordinates in .shx fie,  for example: polygon for Pune  city , Nasik city , Nanded city , now I want to polygon co-ordinates for  only Pune city, So I need to edit that .shx file and  get only for pune polygon co-ordinates. any hints?

Comment: @KiranPrajapati shx file are shape indexes and not the geometry. you can get info from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile

Comment: All the .shx holds is a 100 byte header (which is identical to the .shp header) and the offset and record length data for the .shp. It's best not to reference specific files if you don't understand how they work  ("I want coordinate data out of a shapefile" is much more effective).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save your .shp file as .geojson file in qgis. Right click on layer and click on save as then select geoJSON formate. geoJSON file is human readable file, so you can view all the coordinates. You can also edit them and after edit you can again save file as .shp file.

Comment: Depending on the coordinate reference system of your shapefile data, this may or may not be a good idea. GeoJSON supports a limited set of CRS

Answer (score 2):

QGIS has a function "Extract Nodes", under the "Vector->Geometry Tools" menu. This creates a point vector layer of all the nodes in a polygon layer. Then you can use the Field Calculator to add two columns for X and Y coordinates in this new point shapefile, and finally "Save as..." and save to a csv.